# Is a RV(1) a markov chain?

Tags: regression, probability, self-study, markov-process

Consider the process $X_1$, $X_2$,... defined by $X_n=\alpha\ X_{n-1}+\epsilon_n$ where $\epsilon_i$ is independent random variable for all $i$ , $X_0=0$ and $\alpha$ is a constant. Does this process satisfy the Markov property?
\
I said yes, because according to its definition, next value of the process only depends on the current value. However, I am not sure that whether it is necessary for $\epsilon_i$'s to be i.i.d or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to prove independence between $X_n$ and any $X_i$ $(i<n-1)$ given $X_{n=1}$.

Comment: But how can I show that? Could you explain more?

Comment: $P(X_n=x/X_{n-1}=y)=P(\epsilon_n=x-\alpha\ y)$. Therefore, $X_n$ only depends on $X_{n-1}. Is it correct?

Comment: Show that Xn has a probability distribution that depends only on X(n-1) and not any Xi before that. Initial conditions are X0 =0 and X1= e1, Then X2= (alpha) X1 +e1..  So take it from there.

Comment: @Xi'an: I could not find any proof, in different references, I found: since it is an autoregressive process, next value is only depends on the current value, but the only thing that I am not sure about is that $\epsilon_i$'s should be i.i.d or independecy is enough to say that this RV(1) is a markov chain. I really apreciate your help